# Is there a way to create an encrypted email with no third party application

Tags: encryption

I would like to send and receive emails between group of people. Is there a way to create it with no need to use some other 3rd party application. Is there a way just to transfer files between 2 people so there won't be any way to decrypt it by any other technology?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad ​ ​

Comment: Thanks @Ricky, I know the one time pad. I would like to know if there is a practical way to implement it (is there a code I can use)? and if there is a real life experience with it since I heard for short message it can be easily decrypted?

Comment: Oh, this question actually makes more sense than I'd originally thought. ​ (I had missed its initial "other".) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: What do you mean by "third party application"? You could of course write your own program... And some email clients may support some forms of encryption.

Comment: Thanks @otus, you are right. I meant a reliable application or any open source code that is reliable.

Comment: @Avi, code and software recommendations are off topic here and tend to be closed. I think your question would be better asked on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (If you agree, you should delete the question here first, because cross posting is not allowed.)

Comment: I ask for methodology as well.

Comment: You could host the emails on your own server and encrypt them with PGP. But after reading your comment: <blockquote>Thanks @otus, you are right. I meant a reliable application or any open source code that is reliable.</blockquote>
if I'm understanding you correctly you want to build your own encryption from the ground up? Unless you're a cryptographer by trade, don't do that. I believe the real problem here is that you're gravely misinformed. In today's world, cryptographic vulnerabilities rarely arise from the underlying algorithms utilized for encryption and decryption. These vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GPG (a.k.a. PGP) or S/MIME.

For additional security, you may also want to use a PGP smartcard and generate your encryption keys in the PGP smartcard. This way, even you don't know your own private key and can't accidentally leak your private key. The only way to leak private key with PGP smartcard is if you lose your card or if there's a vulnerability in the card itself.

Using GPG, you only need to depend on the open source GPG software itself. You can use email client plugin for convenience, but you can also just copy and paste your encrypted message between GPG and the email client.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what email host you use. Hosts like Gmail have built in SSL encryption. There are other standards like the S/MIME encryption feature built into Microsoft Outlook. Check out this post https://superuser.com/questions/25658/gmail-and-ssl-encryption-how-much-is-encrypted

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tyvonne Boykin. I'm aware of these feature. As far as I read the problem with them is that the hosting companies might have back door for decrypting the email. That's why I'm looking for some reliable way to transfer the emails.

Comment: This is about end-to-end encryption between the sender and recipient, so TLS and the link you included are irrelevant. However, S/MIME is very relevant if the email client supports it. Perhaps you'd like to expand upon that point?